# How to split the string with the difference of newline?

Tags: c

In this code, I am splitting the string by the difference of newline `"\n"`. I could use `strtok` for this purpose but I am not using it. I just want to get a specific substring from the string. like

**Expected result:**

```
printf("%s\n", word[0]);
Hello World

printf("%s\n", word[1]);
How are you?
```

**Given result:**

```
printf("%s\n", word[0]);
Hello World
How are you?

printf("%s\n", word[1]);
d
How are you?
```

I don't know what is wrong with this code that it is giving me this type of result.

**Code**

```
int main(){
  char words[10][10];
  int indexCtr = 0, wordIndex = 0, totalWords = 0;
  char string[100] = "Hello World\nhow are you?";

  for(indexCtr = 0; indexCtr <= strlen(string); indexCtr++){
    if(string[indexCtr] == "\n" || string[indexCtr] == '\0'){
      words[totalWords][wordIndex] = '\0';
      totalWords++;
      wordIndex = 0;
    }
    else{
      words[totalWords][wordIndex] = string[indexCtr];
      wordIndex++;
    }
  }
  printf("%s\n", words[0]);
}
```

Comment: `string[indexCtr] == "\n"` should be barking a warning comparing `char` to `char *` . If it isn't, time to crank up your warning level. That should be `string[indexCtr] == '\n'`. And fyi, both of those sentences including their terminators are longer than 10 char, so you're breaching your `words` inferior array dimensions and invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: I used `printf("%s\n", word[0])` and wrote `string[indexCtr] == '\n'` but it is giving me the result **Hello Worlhow are you!**

Comment: Did you read what I said?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes I read and answered you

Comment: I didn't ask a question, so I'm not clear what you're answering. The two significant things I pointed are are deal breakers to your code working properly. They *both* have to be fixed, especially the latter or your code invokes undefined behavior, and any output you see is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared

```
char words[10][10];
```

So, that will fit "Hello Worl" with no space for a null at the end.

Make them words bigger.
Are you sure you won't have more than ten words? Watch out for that in your loop too.
Clearly it's not a problem for this string, but beware.

(Also compare a character '\n' rather than the string literal as pointed out in the comments.)